# Can I get all tags used in django-taggit short of raw sql?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-taggit

I want to have a user select tags with a radio button widget, not with a char box.  So I want to get all candidate tags as in "SELECT slug,name FROM taggit_tag;".  Is there a way to do that without issuing raw sql?  (I am shy of the transaction handling, which has bit me in the past.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
from taggit.models import Tag
tags = Tag.objects.all()
```